# Passing arguments when running programs via ActiveXObject (JScript)?

Tags: xml, vbscript, jscript, wsh

Trying to write a windows speech recognition macro. Written using XML and scripting language is JScript. Using `ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")`, executables can be, well, executed. But how can we pass an argument to this executable ? Like, if I were to open IE using the above, how can I pass an argument so that it loads with a specified URL(argument) ?

In XML, we could write :

```
<run command = "C:\Program Files\BlahBlah\MusicPlayer.exe" params = "D:\Music\Music1.mp3"/>
```

How to do this in JScript ? Or VBScript?
Any help appreciated. :)

Comment: It's a long time ago, but if I'm correct, you can supply parameters in a space-separated list. Eg: `var ws = ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");ws.Run('"C:\Program Files\BlahBlah\MusicPlayer.exe" "D:\Music\Music1.mp3"');`

Comment: [`WScript.Shell` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run this from JS. I created a console application which accepts an argument and invoked it from web application.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function RunEXE() {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

        var prog = "D:\\FetchParam.exe";
        oShell.Run('"' + prog + '" INITParam', 1);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
    function RunEXE( exeApp, para ) {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        oShell.Run( "\"" + exeApp + "\"" + "\"" + para + "\"", 1 );
    }

    RunEXE ( "D:\\ProgFiles\\player.exe", "D:\\My Music\\ music.mp3" )
</script>
```